# didRangeBeacons call back always triggered with empty array of beacon

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

I'm using core location library in iOS for finding beacons, I'm in beacon region and the didRangeBeacons callback is triggering but it is always returning an empty array of beacons.

Please find the attached sample code. I have beacon immediate to iPhone, but still, beacon region state is inside when app opened and immediately it is changed to outside state and we are getting an empty array in didRangeBeacons. I have included both NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription. The NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription keys are in the info.plist. The application has location permission set to "always". I'm using both Estimote and Kontakt beacons. OS version is iOS 11.2.6, Device iPhone 5s, Xcode 9.2.

```
 #import "CoreLocationViewController.h"

@interface CoreLocationViewController ()
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLBeaconRegion *beacon_region;

}
@end

@implementation CoreLocationViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"CoreLocationViewController viewDidLoad");

    NSUUID *ProximityUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"b94f62c8-1af4-11e8-accf-0ed5f89f718b"];
    beacon_region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:ProximityUUID identifier:@"abqwercds"];
    [beacon_region setNotifyEntryStateOnDisplay:YES];
    [beacon_region setNotifyOnExit:YES];
    [beacon_region setNotifyOnEntry:YES];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;

    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){

        NSLog(@"Location Services Enabled");

        if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER){

            NSLog(@"We are in LocationServicesRequestViewController IS_OS_8_OR_LATER");

            NSUInteger code = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

            NSLog(@"CLLocationManager authorizationStatus %lu",(unsigned long)code);

            if (code == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
                NSLog(@"kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined");
                [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
            }
        }else{
            NSLog(@"We are in LocationServicesRequestViewController IS_OS_8_BELOW");
        }

    }else{
        NSLog(@"authorizationStatus ");
    }

}

#pragma mark Location Manager Delegate methods
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"locationManager Error %@",error);
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status{
     NSLog(@"Status of location service is %d",status);
    if ((status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) || (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse)){
         NSLog(@"location service status changed 1");
        [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beacon_region];
        [locationManager requestStateForRegion:beacon_region];
    }else{
         NSLog(@"location service status changed 2");
    }
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region{

     NSLog(@"CLLocationManager Beacon Region State Determine ");

    switch (state) {
        case CLRegionStateUnknown:
        {
             NSLog(@" CLLocationManager Region state is unknown %@",region);
            [locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:beacon_region];
            break;
        }
        case CLRegionStateInside:
        {
             NSLog(@" CLLocationManager Region state is In-Side %@",region);

            [locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beacon_region];
        }
        case CLRegionStateOutside:
        {
             NSLog(@" CLLocationManager Region state is Out-Side %@",beacon_region);

            [locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:beacon_region];

            break;
        }
    }

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{

     NSLog(@" CLLocationManager Enter into Region %@",region);

    [locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beacon_region];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

    NSLog(@"didExitRegion location manager %@",region );

    [locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:beacon_region];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region{

    NSLog(@"CLLocationManager Beacon Monitoring Started for the region %@",region);

}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"CLLocationManager Monitoring of beacon region %@ is failed, Error %@",region,error);
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager rangingBeaconsDidFailForRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"CLLocationManager ranging of beacon region %@ is failed, Error %@",region.proximityUUID,error);
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray<CLBeacon *> *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"beacons %@",beacons);
}
```

[image: Beacon Configuration image][image: Application Location Permission]

[image: Logs]

[image: Kontakt Beacon configuration]

Comment: Can you make sure your UUIS is correct? Also is authorisation requested and then given? I see it in the code, just asking if it gets triggered.

Comment: Beacon UUID and Location permission is good and correct, please find the attached screenshots

Comment: Can you show the logs you get on launching the app?

Comment: @davidgyoung I have updated logs screenshot can you have a look

Comment: The screenshot shows an inside beacon region callback, followed by an *outside* beacon region callback.  So it sounds like you are "outside" and as a result you should not get anything in the didRangeBeacons callback.  Have you tried detecting your beacon with an off-the-shelf app?

Comment: Yes but My beacons are immediate to the iPhone still state of the beacon region is changing from inside to outside immediately. I don't know how it is happening

Comment: Hey, guys, the issue is with Devices iPhone 5S